# How to enable NFC on Galaxy Note I717 for lockscreen/screen off use?

Tags: custom-roms, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note, nfc

The Note I717 running Paranoid ICS and makes everything except the S-Pen great -- except I can't quite figure out how to enable NFC for use on the lock screen/screen off modes.

I see plenty of people doing this and it appears to require a software mod of some kind. How can I get this rigged up on the I717?

Comment: This might be disabled by default for security reasons,  just FYI.

Comment: Security, battery, whatnot... that's fine and dandy. Still eager to do it despite the security implications. Thank you for the thought ce4 :-)

Comment: That remark was just meant as a note :-) You might get tracked, someone could launch things (e.g. the browser with a nfc provided URL and so on). Not wanting to prevent you doing it here.